# Why do we need SSH keys in git?

Tags: git, ssh

I am having a very little or no familiarity with git.I have been following a tutorial and there the person generate ssh keys, this was my first encounter with it.
Prior to it, i was following the command written in the git or adding it directly by JetBrains ide.
I know it should be encrypting the connection but when uploading to GitHub, it means I am making my code public. Then why encryption? Why going all these troubles in cmd.

Comment: quoting [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) With SSH keys, you can connect to GitHub without supplying your username or password at each visit.

Comment: and what about the https...?

Comment: Because you want to get the correct version of a repo even if someone is actively trying to replace it with their (malicious) version.

Comment: I am very sorry please bear with me, but there is ID password for that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The connection encryption and the authentication has nothing to do with safeguarding the contents of the repository, insofar as they are means to block 3rd parties from accessing it, but if they do have access, you using ssh won't magically prevent you from cloning/pulling malicious content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do we need SSH keys in git?

SSH keys identify the user that is interacting with the git remote repository.

> I know it should be encrypting the connection but when uploading to GitHub, it means I am making my code public.

Not necessarily, there are private repositories in GitHub. Also, there are other hosting providers as well.

> Why going all these troubles in cmd.

With SSH authentication you don't need to enter your credentials when interacting with the remote.

Comment: I just created a repo in my account with cmd without ID or password, without using SSH ?

Comment: Then you are using some credential helper.

Comment: You obviously are, if you were not prompted for credentials.

Comment: I dont know what i am missing now :-|

Comment: Due, to some reason i have to format my lapi, and yes it ask for ID and Password first time you try to commit anything in your repo. Thanks for help

Comment: I understand all the answers. But still: If i want to clone a public repo to my server, why is SSH (sometimes?) needed. After all, it is a -public- repo. Could it be a security question - to prevent changes in code during transport? It seem logical and the only explanation I can think of. But if so, why doesn't GitHub enforce it globally?

Comment: @Marko36 I'm not aware of any situation where SSH is required for cloning a public repo.

Comment: @1615903 https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample requires SSH for cloning. At least it did in my case. I can reproduce ot and put up some screenshots, if you want.

Comment: '@Marko36 thanks for your help, its really late but i got all now